# Finding specified text above found text

Tags: regex, search, text

Okay what im trying to do is find the closest text before my searched word

for example

searched word is `CAT`

from the following

```
I like PC1 my PC2 is fast CAT for my PC3
```

i want it to locate the word CAT then return PC2 and not the others just the first one found before `CAT`

Comment: Great. Lets see the regex you tried it with...

Comment: I'm sorry but that question makes no sense to me. Can you detail ;ore and provide clearer input/wanted output? Also, where is your current code failing?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want to find excerpt around your search key word if it is so you can try

```
var searchTerm = "CAT";
var searchExcp = "\\b(.){0,14}" + searchTerm + "(.){0,5}((.)+\\b){0,14}";
searchExcp = new RegExp(searchExcp, "gi");
```

"searchExcp" is a regex u can use to perform search,

PS: this is javascipt code.